# How do I make a (desktop) shortcut to play a specific folder in the new Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-11, shortcuts, windows-media-player, media-player, file-shortcut

I have experience with you being able to make a shortcut for VLC where you specify VLC's .exe location, then you add "-LZ" with the folder location after that to start playing media (music) from a folder and I want to know if the same is possible with the new windows media player, because the app layout is not terrible and it accepts the buttons on my Bluetooth headphones, which isn't standard in VLC.
I know there is an option to add files in the Media Player with an option to add an entire folder and I use this currently (clear play queue and add the folder), but I want to know if there is a faster way.

Comment: Do you want to play "whatever is in folder x" or just a playlist that contains items that are currently in folder x? Have you tried making a playlist?

Comment: @Gantendo I want it to play everything in folder X, which changes, and I would rather not have to update the playlist every time. Also media player seemed to have problems with playlists taking a long time "indexing libraries" for ~400 songs.

Comment: I have simple batch files to generate M3U files that do exactly this.  It doesn't take my computer but a nano-second to generate a playlist.  I understand this isn't what you are looking for but though I would share how I have deal with the problem in the past.. but to be fair.. i am still running hyper-old winamp and don't bother with MS players.  Winamp kicks the llama's a**.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas believe me, I also would rather not bother with MS players, but that is the only player I used that looks decent and accepts Bluetooth media controls. Unfortunately, VLC doesn't do this, although it is perfect in every other way. Would you or someone know how to get the Bluetooth media controls in VLC? It doesn't recognise the buttons when I try to reassign hotkeys.